# Time interval difference between dates in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to analyze the time interval difference from two dates in **Amazon-Redshift**, for example:

```
'2021-10-13 14:37:00' - '2021-10-13 12:00:00' = '02:37:00'
```

or in case the days is different:

```
'2021-10-13 14:37:00' - '2021-10-12 12:00:00' = '26:37:00'
```

I figured out only `datediff()` function. This function only return part from what I want.

So, is there a way better to return the result that I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract them using `-` to get an `INTERVAL`. Then, you can just format the interval according to your needs. For example:

```
select to_char(timestamp '2021-10-13 14:37:00' - 
               timestamp '2021-10-13 12:00:00', 'HH:MI:SS')
```

Result:

```
02:37:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yeah, it works. I tested it. But, when I put the fields in place of these strings the subtraction returns an empty interval, because of that, the `to_char` returns an error.  (NOTICE: Function "to_char(interval,text)" not supported.)

Comment: @RanierCordeiro What's the data type of those fields? `TIMESTAMP` or something else?

Comment: Yeah, it's `TIMESTAMP`. Also I tried explicit force it with `:: timestamp` each column when I call the function for example: `to_char(filed_2 :: timestamp without time zone - field_1 :: timestamp without time zone, 'HH:MI:SS')` but the error is the same.